# How to change Websites URL without using 301 redirection?

Tags: seo

I am using a CMS based on aspx which haven't any option for 301 redirection. I need to change URL for the services page or few more pages 
For example I want to change (http://www.theedmontoncontractors.com/services.html) to (http://www.theedmontoncontractors.com/door-windows-installation-services.html). 
Please let me know a search engine friendly answer.

1. I don't want let people find any 404 error page while go through /services.html via search engine
2. I also want search engine should not read or index /services.html page for future.

Comment: Why the change ? If for keywords in url, really dont bother.

Comment: I have seen only SEO friendly URL's takes place in search engine

Comment: No, this is not worth changing your urls for, especially since you cant redirect.

Comment: actually I have 3 pages (product/door, project/door and project-door) all have "door" in their URL, hence I was looking to change URL. Do you not think that my link-juice would dived into above three URL's.

Comment: You need to look at the bigger picture. Have a read of this seo guide : http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.co.uk/en/uk/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf